# How can I efficiently concatenate images in a Tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I currently have sixteen images (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,...) which must be concatenated into one as part of a Tensorflow Dataset workflow. Each image is 128 x 128 and has the shape of (128, 128, 3). The final output should be a 512 x 512 image of shape (512,512,3). All of the images come from an image sequence, known as `img_seq`. This img_seq has the shape of (None, 128, 128, 3)

Right now, this is accomplished through the following code:

```
@tf.function
def glue_to_one(imgs_seq):
    first_row= tf.concat((imgs_seq[0], imgs_seq[1],imgs_seq[2],imgs_seq[3]), 0)
    second_row = tf.concat((imgs_seq[4], imgs_seq[5], imgs_seq[6], imgs_seq[7]), 0)
    third_row = tf.concat((imgs_seq[8], imgs_seq[9], imgs_seq[10], imgs_seq[11]), 0)
    fourth_row = tf.concat((imgs_seq[12], imgs_seq[13], imgs_seq[14], imgs_seq[15]), 0)

    img_glue = tf.stack((first_row, second_row, third_row, fourth_row), axis=1)
    img_glue = tf.reshape(img_glue, [512,512,3])

    return img_glue
```

It is suspected that this method is inefficient and is learning to a bottleneck.
A different approach would be to allocate a 512 x 512 tensor and then replace the elements. Would this be more efficient? How would it be done? Can you please recommend a better approach?

Comment: The selected answer is the slowest and also doesn't reproduce the above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use tf.split method instead of writing that much code...,

```
**Your Inputs seems to be a list of inputs**
```

```
def stack_and_concat(x):
    t = tf.split(x , 16 , axis=0)

    t = tf.reshape(tf.stack([tf.concat(t[(i*4): 4 * (i+1)] , axis=1) for i in range(4)],axis=2) , (512,512,3))
    
    return t
```

```
concat_inputs(x).shape
```

```
TensorShape([512, 512, 3])
```

for thousand iterations my method took **`3.28 secs`** but your's took **`10.35 secs`**

Comment: This method does not include all 16 tiles. Instead, 4 tiles are duplicated along the X axis. I apologize for not stating earlier but the input shape is (None , 128 , 128, 3) instead of (16 , 128 , 128, 3)

Comment: The batch_shape is None. Therefore this method doesn't work. The input shape is (None , 128 , 128, 3).

Comment: Now, this will work for batch_size=None also.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Now, Fixed the issue, actually we have to get a constant value from tf.shape().

Comment: No, not really. I think I need to send you an example of the Tensorflow Dataset so you can see how the image is being created.

Comment: @Mohammed Ahmed Here is the paste: https://pastebin.com/SMiDnEBA

Comment: At my end it is working fine, so what's the matter? You are loading images in a sequence but one thing to remember the data which shall be going to this function should have the shape of (1, 16, 128,128,3) other than that it throws an error, here 1 is the batch size you can take more than that.

Comment: Now, check it once more,

Comment: @Mohammed Ahmed:
The shape of the input into the function is: (None, 128, 128, 3)
The type of the input is: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

Comment: if it is None then how you are fetching the sixteen sequences at one time? that's my question.

Comment: The method of doing direct indexing using `imgs_seq[0]` seems to be working.

Comment: can you tell me what's the output shape or what's this function returning?
```DatasetAugmentImages(decoded_images, label):```

Comment: what's this function doing here ```DataAugmentation.augmentImage```?

Comment: DataAugmentation.augmentImage is performing operations to alter the image (increase brightness, flip the image etc). It can be ignored as it doesn't alter the input shape as far as I'm aware. I have 3 custom tensorflow datasets and 2 of them don't utilize it.

Comment: Use the code above and show me the error, what is he saying?

Comment: The glued together image from the code is incorrect. This is what it produces:
https://pasteboard.co/KrWk4Q54ilWY.png.

Notice how the image tiles are duplicated along the x-dimension?

Comment: This is an example of a correct image from a batch:
https://pasteboard.co/Seg3CFgXvUdR.png

Comment: Update the answer Now, this should work and kindly upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve it about 3 times using something like this:

```
def glue_answer(imgs_seq):
    image = tf.reshape(imgs_seq, (4, 4, 128, 128, 3))
    image = tf.concat(image, axis=1)
    image = tf.concat(image, axis=1)
    
    return image
```

I tested the performance as follows:

```
def glue_to_one(imgs_seq):
    first_row= tf.concat((imgs_seq[0], imgs_seq[1],imgs_seq[2],imgs_seq[3]), 0)
    second_row = tf.concat((imgs_seq[4], imgs_seq[5], imgs_seq[6], imgs_seq[7]), 0)
    third_row = tf.concat((imgs_seq[8], imgs_seq[9], imgs_seq[10], imgs_seq[11]), 0)
    fourth_row = tf.concat((imgs_seq[12], imgs_seq[13], imgs_seq[14], imgs_seq[15]), 0)

    img_glue = tf.stack((first_row, second_row, third_row, fourth_row), axis=1)
    img_glue = tf.reshape(img_glue, [512,512,3])

    return img_glue

def glue_answer(imgs_seq):
    image = tf.reshape(imgs_seq, (4, 4, 128, 128, 3))
    image = tf.concat(image, axis=1)
    image = tf.concat(image, axis=1)
    
    return image

print("Method in question:")
%timeit -n 1000 -r 10 glue_to_one(imgs_seq)
print("Method in answe:")
%timeit -n 1000 -r 10 glue_answer(imgs_seq)
```

Output:

```
Method in question:
1.7 ms ± 212 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1,000 loops each)
Method in answe:
540 µs ± 28.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: This answer does not produce the same output shape of (512,512,3)

Comment: @TomLin Oh that is true. I forgot tf concat is not the same as np concatenate. It works with np concatenate but its 2 times slower than your solution. I will check it more.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.squeeze(tf.concat(tf.split(tf.concat(imgs_seq, axis=0),4),axis=1))`

Testing:

```
imgs_seq = [ tf.random.normal(shape=(128,128,3)) for _ in range(16)]
out1 = glue_to_one(imgs_seq)
out2 = tf.squeeze(tf.concat(tf.split(tf.concat(imgs_seq, axis=0),4),axis=1))

#check whether both outputs are same.
np.testing.assert_allclose(out1.numpy(), out2.numpy())

%timeit glue_to_one(imgs_seq)
1.52 ms ± 123 µs per loop 
   
%timeit tf.squeeze(tf.concat(tf.split(tf.concat(imgs_seq,axis=0),4),axis=1))   
308 µs ± 13.6 µs per loop
```